# ImageMagick isn't installed when it really should be

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, imagemagick, paperclip, macports

Some context:

- Mac OSX 10.8.5
- Rails 3.2.15

I know there are many ImageMagick questions up, but none of them seem to help. Any help is appreciated!

I'm working on an app that uses the paperclip gem for photo attachments. It has worked without a hitch on other computers (where ImageMagick was already installed). My seed file uploads images.

I try to run

```
bundle exec rake db:reset
```

but eventually I get...

```
rake aborted!
Validation failed: Photo file Could not run the `identify` command. Please install
ImageMagick., Photo file Could not run the `identify` command. Please install
ImageMagick.
```

So I dutifully try

```
sudo port uninstall ImageMagick
sudo port install ImageMagick
which identify
```

and nothing happens.

It might be important that although installing ImageMagick seems to work, it does yell at me:

```
Warning: Your DNS servers incorrectly claim to know the address of nonexistent
hosts. This may cause checksum mismatches for some ports.
```

EDIT:

The solution is simple. I added the following like to my .bash_profile file.

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

I wish I could explain how that worked.

Comment: Has your `$PATH` been configured to map binaries under `/opt/local/bin`?

Comment: Thank you! How did you know? And that seems like the sort of thing that should be a default...

Comment: Great! Post your solution as an answer & accept it. Include any additional links & resources, so other folks can solve similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was add the following to my .bash_profile

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```